# Maintaining RecyclerView and fragment back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I'm  currently having trouble restoring my fragment to it's previous state after clicking into a detail activity from my recyclerview adapter. The back button within the detail activity returns me to an empty fragment with no data.

Here's the detail activity class

```
**
 * Provides UI for the Detail page with Collapsing Toolbar.
 */
public class DetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static final String EXTRA_POSITION = "position";
    private Boolean isFabOpen = false;
    private FloatingActionButton fab,fab1,fab2;
    private Animation fab_open,fab_close,rotate_forward,rotate_backward;
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout collapTool;
    private LinearLayout linLayout;
    private boolean isFavorited;
    private boolean isIgnored;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab1 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab1);
        fab2 = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab2);
        fab_open = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.fab_open);
        fab_close = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.fab_close);
        rotate_forward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_forward);
        rotate_backward = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.rotate_backward);
        fab.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab1.setOnClickListener(this);
        fab2.setOnClickListener(this);

        //Getting the details passed from the last activity to parse proper detail display
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle bd = intent.getExtras();
        String titleText = (String) bd.get("titleText");
        String descriptionText = (String) bd.get("description");
        String locations = (String) bd.get("locations");
        String assetTypes = (String) bd.get("assetTypes");
        String propertyStatuses = (String) bd.get("propertyStatuses");
        String buyerId = (String) bd.get("buyer_id") + "";

        //Buyer ID testing if proper ID is passed through
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),buyerId,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        isFavorited = (Boolean) bd.get("favorited");
        isIgnored = (Boolean) bd.get("ignored");

        //If item was favorited from previous page, adjust accordingly
        if(isFavorited) {
            fab2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#7E57C2")));
            fab1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#133253")));
            fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#7E57C2")));
            isFavorited = true;
            isIgnored = false;
        }
        //If item was ignored from previous page, adjust accordingly
        if(isIgnored) {
            fab1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#EF5350")));
            fab2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#133253")));
            fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#EF5350")));
            isIgnored = true;
            isFavorited = false;
        }
        setSupportActionBar((Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        linLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linLay);
        collapTool = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        linLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isFabOpen) {
                    fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
                    fab1.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab1.setClickable(false);
                    fab2.setClickable(false);
                    isFabOpen = false;
                }
            }
        });

        collapTool.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(isFabOpen) {
                    fab.startAnimation(rotate_backward);
                    fab1.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab2.startAnimation(fab_close);
                    fab1.setClickable(false);
                    fab2.setClickable(false);
                    isFabOpen = false;
                }
            }
        });

        locations = locations.replace("Locations | ", "");
        assetTypes = assetTypes.replace("Asset Types | ", "");
        propertyStatuses = propertyStatuses.replace("Property Statuses | ", "");

        // Set Collapsing Toolbar layout to the screen
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar =
                (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        // Set title of Detail page
        // collapsingToolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.item_title));

        assert fab2 != null;
        fab2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isFavorited) {
                    fab2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#7E57C2")));
                    fab1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#133253")));
                    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#7E57C2")));
                    //Snackbar.make(v, "Favorited...",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    isFavorited = true;
                    isIgnored = false;
                } else {
                    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#133253")));
                    fab2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#133253")));
                    /*Snackbar.make(v, "Unfavorited...",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            */
                    isFavorited = false;
                }
            }
        });

        assert fab1 != null;
        fab1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!isIgnored) {
                    fab1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#EF5350")));
                    fab2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#133253")));
                    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#EF5350")));
                    isIgnored = true;
                    isFavorited = false;
                } else {
                    fab1.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#133253")));
                    fab.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#133253")));
                    /*Snackbar.make(v, "Unfavorited...",
                            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            */
                    isIgnored = false;
                }
            }
        });



        int postion = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_POSITION, 0);
        Resources resources = getResources();
        String[] places = resources.getStringArray(R.array.city_array);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle(titleText);

        String[] placeDetails = resources.getStringArray(R.array.city_array);
        TextView placeDetail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_detail);
        placeDetail.setText(descriptionText);

        String[] placeLocations = resources.getStringArray(R.array.city_array);
        TextView placeLocation =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_location);
        placeLocation.setText(locations);

        TextView assetDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.asset_details);
        assetDetails.setText(assetTypes);

        TextView propertyDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_details);
        propertyDetails.setText(propertyStatuses);

        /*
        TextView investmentDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.investment_details);
        investmentDetails.setText(investmentRangeMin);
        */

        /*

        TypedArray placePictures = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.city_array);
        ImageView placePicutre = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        placePicutre.setImageDrawable(placePictures.getDrawable(postion % placePictures.length()));

        placePictures.recycle();
        */
    }
```

And here is my recyclerView adapter that has an onclicklistener for the item view which creates the detail activity.

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private static List<BuyerProfile> profileItems;
    private static boolean itemFavorited;

    RVAdapter(List<BuyerProfile> profiles) {
        this.profileItems = profiles;
    }

    public static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView description;
        TextView locations;
        TextView id;
        TextView investmentRange;
        TextView investmentRangeMax;
        TextView assetTypes;
        TextView propertyStatuses;
        TextView profileId;
        ImageView headerImage;
        Button favoriteButton;
        Button ignoreButton;
        CardView cardView;
        private ImageView spacer;
        private boolean favorited = false;
        private boolean ignored = false;
        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
            description = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.descriptionText);
            investmentRange = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.investment);
            //investmentRangeMax = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.investmentRangeMax);
            locations = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.locations);
            id = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.profileNumber);
            headerImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBillionaire);
            assetTypes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.assetTypes);
            propertyStatuses = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.propertyStatuses);
            favoriteButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.action_button);
            ignoreButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ignore_button);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            profileId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.buyer_id);
            spacer = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.spacerImage);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int i = getAdapterPosition();
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(DetailActivity.EXTRA_POSITION, getAdapterPosition());
                    intent.putExtra("titleText", name.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("description", description.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("locations", locations.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("assetTypes", assetTypes.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("propertyStatuses", propertyStatuses.getText());
                    intent.putExtra("favorited", favorited);
                    intent.putExtra("ignored", ignored);
                    HomeFragment homeReturn = new HomeFragment();
                    // intent.putExtra("buyer_id", profileId.getText());
                    //intent.putExtra("investmentRangeMin", investmentRangeMin.getText());
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

            /*
            favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!favorited) {
                        spacer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        headerImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7E57C2"));
                        favorited = true;
                        ignored = false;
                    } else {
                        spacer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        favorited = false;
                        headerImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#42A5F5"));
                    }
                }
            });
            */

            ignoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(!ignored) {
                        spacer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        headerImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#EF5350"));
                        favorited = false;
                        ignored = true;
                    } else {
                        ignored = false;
                        spacer.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        headerImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#133253"));
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return profileItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, viewGroup, false);
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, int i) {
        final PersonViewHolder selectedCard = personViewHolder;
        selectedCard.name.setText(profileItems.get(i).getBuyerProfTitle());
        selectedCard.description.setText(profileItems.get(i).getDescription());
        selectedCard.locations.setText("Locations |  " + profileItems.get(i).parseLocations());
        selectedCard.assetTypes.setText("Asset Types | " + profileItems.get(i).getAssetTypes());
        selectedCard.propertyStatuses.setText("Property Statuses | " + profileItems.get(i).getPropertyStatuses());
        selectedCard.investmentRange.setText("Investment Range | $125,000 - $250,000");
        final int position = i;
        personViewHolder.ignoreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                profileItems.remove(position);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(position, getItemCount());
            }
        });

        selectedCard.favoriteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(!selectedCard.favorited) {
                    profileItems.get(position).favoriteItem();
                    selectedCard.spacer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    selectedCard.spacer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFF176"));
                    selectedCard.headerImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#7E57C2"));
                    selectedCard.favorited = true;
                    selectedCard.ignored = false;
                } else {
                    profileItems.get(position).unfavoriteItem();
                    selectedCard.favorited = false;
                    selectedCard.headerImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#133253"));
                }
            }
        });
        //personViewHolder.profileId.setText(profileItems.get(i).getProfileId() + "");
        //personViewHolder.investmentRangeMin.setText(profileItems.get(i).getInvestmentRangeMin());
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

And finally here is my main fragment which holds the recyclerview.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private CustomListAdapter listAdapter;
    //private static final String profileUrl = "http://172.16.98.152:3000/apip/buyers/profiles";
    private static final String matchesUrl = "http://172.16.98.152:3000/apip/sellers/profiles/1/matches";
    private String matched = "http://172.16.98.152:3000/apip/sellers/profiles/";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private ListView listView;
    private List<BuyerProfile> buyersProfiles = new ArrayList<BuyerProfile>();
    private View root;
    private TextView noItems;
    private TextView search;
    private TextView searchSecondLine;
    private LinearLayoutManager llm;
    private String profileUrlString;
    private String KEY_RECYCLER_STATE = "recycleSave";
    private Bundle viewState;
    private Bundle arguments;
    private RecyclerView rv;
    private int mStackLevel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        noItems = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
        search = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchSecondLine = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.matchesSecondLine);
        rv = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL_LIST));
        llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        final RVAdapter recyclerAdapter = new RVAdapter(buyersProfiles);
        rv.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
        arguments = getArguments();

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            matched = matched + savedInstanceState.getString("profileArgs") + "/matches";
        } else {
            if(arguments != null && arguments.containsKey("profileId")) {
                matched = matched + arguments.getString("profileId") + "/matches";
                search.setText("Search: " + arguments.getString("locations") + " " + arguments.getString("assetTypes"));
                searchSecondLine.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchSecondLine.setText(arguments.getString("propertyStatuses"));
            } else {
                matched = "http://172.16.98.152:3000/apip/sellers/profiles/1/matches";
                noItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchSecondLine.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                rv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                search.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getActivity().getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);

        Network network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
        mRequestQueue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        mRequestQueue.start();


        JsonArrayRequest profileRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(matched,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                BuyerProfile parsedProfile = new BuyerProfile();
                                parsedProfile.setBuyerProfTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                parsedProfile.setDescription(obj.getString("description"));
                                parsedProfile.setLocations(obj.getString("location"));
                                parsedProfile.setAssetTypes(obj.getString("asset_type"));
                                //parsedProfile.setProfileId(obj.getString("id"));
                                parsedProfile.setPropertyStatuses(obj.getString("property_status"));
                                //parsedProfile.setProfileId(obj.getInt("buyer_profile_id"));
                                parsedProfile.unfavoriteItem();
                                buyersProfiles.add(parsedProfile);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        //hidePDialog();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Toast.makeText(selectBuyerProfile.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        mRequestQueue.add(profileRequest);
        /*
        if(buyersProfiles.isEmpty()) {
            rv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            noItems.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        */
        return root;
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        if(arguments != null && arguments.containsKey("profileId")) {
            outState.putString("profileArgs", arguments.getString("profileId"));
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure which of these classes I need to be restoring and how I can restore the previous details and images in HomeFragment after clicking back from the detail activity. I would be able to just describe a parent activity in my manifest but the main class holding everything is a fragment and android doesn't let you choose parent fragments! Any ideas or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove initialization of List from declaration.

> private List buyersProfiles = new ArrayList();

And make initialization in onCreateView method if List is null.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not fix my problem